# git - browse remote repos

Tags: git, ssh, git-remote

Is it possible to browse all the remote repos available on a given server?

I've seen this:

[Git - Browse remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779054/git-browse-remote-repository)

which is about browsing branches in a remote repo. However, I'm assuming this is more of an ssh scripting solution as you need to be able to ssh to the machine and list all the git repos in a certain directory.

Comment: "All the remote repos" - a repo is just a file (or a folder).  The only to find all of them on a machine is to search the entire filesystem.

Comment: No, we have all the remote repos stored in the same directory on the remote server. Given this seems an obvious request I was wondering whether there was a simple ssh command that ssh'd in and did an `ls`.

Comment: Sure.  It's `ssh <your_host> ls <path>`.

Answer (score 0):

No, git alone would not offer that kind of feature.

If you have an intermediate layer between the listener (ssh) and your repo, like **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html)**, then you can call special gitolite commands in order to get all the repos available (that you are authorized to see).

For instance, the **[info command](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#info)**

> `ssh git@host info -h` for help: tells you what version of gitolite and git are on the server, and what repositories you have access to.

To browse their content, you would need an Apache or a [CGit server](http://git.zx2c4.com/cgit/).